# Using arrays and copying into next available row only gives me data in the first cell (user form input)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm making an ERP-system, I have a working, but ugly, code that does what I want. I just tried using arrays for the first time and when using it I only get the first textbox input into my Archive spreadsheet even though I have 9 more textboxes assigned to that array. Kind of hard to explain but easier to see what I'm trying to do in the code.

I have tried changing "B2" for nextRow variable to "C2" but it still gives me only the first textbox input and pastes that into whatever cell is first mentioned in my nextRow variable.

(This code was given to me on the codereview site but I tried to make some changes too it without any luck.

```
'Making the variable that stores the input from all 9 textboxes in the userform
Dim inputs As Variant
'Variabler for inputs
    inputs = Array(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox10.Text, TextBox6.Text, TextBox7.Text, TextBox8.Text, TextBox9.Text)


'Declaring the variable for the next available row from B to J so I can copy the input from each textbox into the corresponding cell in the Archive worksheet.

Dim nextRowB As Range
    Set nextRowB = Sheets("Arkiv").Range("C" & Rows.Count & ":J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    nextRowB.Value = inputs
```

Instead of copying every textbox input over to the corresponding cells it copies only the first textbox input (textbox1) into the first column of the next available row and then lets the rest be empty.

I was expecting this code to paste every textbox input into the next available row in column B all the way to J using the same order I used when assigning the different textbox inputs to the array.

Comment: Try it like `nextRowB.Resize(UBound(inputs), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(inputs)` for pasting the array contents in rows.

Comment: For pasting Array values horizontally in columns may try `nextRowB.Resize(1, UBound(inputs) + 1).Value = inputs`.use +1 with `Ubound(inputs) ` if array base is zero.

Comment: @AhmedAU where exactly? As I said I got this code from another person and tbh I'm a newbie to coding only learnt VBA 3 days ago so I waas using 9 variables and some really ugly code for this before

Comment: Where do you want to paste the array inputs?

Comment: Array inputs are going to the next available row in columns B-J

Comment: last two lines should be `Dim nextRowB As Range` : `Set nextRowB = Sheets("Arkiv").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` and     `nextRowB.Resize(1, UBound(inputs) + 1).Value = inputs`

Comment: Thank you! I got it working now:)

Comment: Welcome. You made my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May try Like this

```
Dim inputs As Variant
inputs = Array(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox10.Text, TextBox6.Text, TextBox7.Text, TextBox8.Text, TextBox9.Text)
Dim nextRowB As Range
Set nextRowB = Sheets("Arkiv").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
nextRowB.Resize(1, UBound(inputs) + 1).Value = inputs
```